# Nuxt/Vue - Is loading thousands of components bad?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i know it sounds rather open ended, but here's the context.

I'm building a simple PWA which is mainly aggregating data and showing it, and on some pages (for example home page), I want to display all these data. These data is represented in components, and I'm iterating through the data loop to generate these components.

I realized on loading my home page, I'm mounting thousands of components and my DOM Size becomes really big. Technically I don't have to load all - just those that the user will see, but I have not really found a way to "lazyload" components?

My components are rather big, they contain images, description, nuxt-links...

My question is whether this is a bad practice, should i implement some form of lazy loading of components? (Only mounting when in sight?) Looking to be pointed in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: You can use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) to know when an element becomes visible on the screen. Or maybe use some kind of virtualized component.